# is this a valid singleton ignoring multi threading

Tags: java, static, singleton, private

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Logger {
    private static final Logger logger = new Logger();
    private static final String test = "value";
    private Logger() {
        System.out.println("Called Constructor!");
    }
    public static Logger getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }
}

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Logger logger;
        Logger logger2 = Logger.getLogger();
    }
}
```

In addition to understanding whether the above code is a singleton or not, I have few more doubts.

Q1) When I created a variable `logger` why is the private constructor not being called and when I called the function `getLogger()` why is the private constructor is being called?

Q2) when is the value of `test` variable gets assigned? before or after private constructor call?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a correct singleton, and it is thread-safe.

> When I created a variable logger why is the private constructor not being called and when I called the function getLogger() why is the private constructor is being called?

Because declaring a variable doesn't do anything other than declaring the variable. It doesn't call any method, and doesn't create any object.

> when is the value of test variable gets assigned? before or after private constructor call?

At the same time, when the class is being initialized.

Comment: my doubt is if the variable test is getting initialised as soon as the class is initialized, why is it not initialising logger (class member)

Comment: It also initializes the logger when the class is initialized. I've clarified my answer.

Comment: @vardin you have two variables named `logger` in your code snippet. One which is `private static final` is initialized when class is loaded by classloader (and variable `test` is initialized at the same time). Another variable called `logger` declared in `main()` is not initialized at all because you only declare it without assigning any value.

Comment: @Ivan why is `private static final logger` not initialised when the class is loaded by class loader?

Comment: @vardin why do you think that it is not initialized? I got message from `System.out.println()` in console

Answer (score 0):

It is a correct singleton:

> When I created a variable logger why is the private constructor not being called and when I called the function getLogger() why is the private constructor is being called?

Soo.. When you declare a variable what you do is to reserve memory space, you are not initializing it with your logger, when declaring a instance of Logger statically inside your logger class java initializes it on the run, then when you call getLogger you are just giving the pointer to that Logger instance.

> when is the value of test variable gets assigned? before or after private constructor call?

Right after your constructor gets called.

Comment: `test` is static so its value is assigned when classloader loads class for the very first time. Constructor has nothing to do with static variables.